# Is there a LinearSnapHelper equivalent in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I couldn't find any alternative to `LinearSnapHelper` in Compose, do any of you know if there is one? If not, do anyone know if there is going to be one in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Accompanist's pager composables](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)?

Comment: Actually It could be perfectly fine in my use case! The only difference I can think of is that when you have LinearSnapHelper you can fling more than one item or drag across more items. But no big deal for me, thank you!

Comment: Even if you conclude that those composables are not a direct solution for your problem, looking at their implementation might give you clues as to how to do this sort of snapping behavior.

Comment: I agree and for my use case it's totally good enough, thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the below library for the equivalent of LinearSnapHelper. It worked for me.
https://github.com/aakarshrestha/compose-pager-snap-helper

The code will look as follows (using LazyRow for listing the items, change to LazyColumn if you want vertical scrolling)

```
ComposePagerSnapHelper(
    width = 320.dp, //required
    content = { listState -> //this param is provided by the method itself, add this param below.
        LazyRow(
            state = listState, //add listState param
        ) {
            items(count = count) { item ->
                //Put your Items Composable here
            }
        }
    }
)
```